# Webpack: Can't resolve module (Stripe.js)

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I've added `Stripe.js` script tag into my `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

I'm getting this error message from webpack:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stripe'

As you can see, `webpack` is not able to resolve `'stripe'` module. I import it using:

```
import 'stripe';
```

So, into my code I'm using `Stripe` keywork in order to get access to `Stripe`:

```
@Injectable()
export class SourceEffects {
  constructor() {
    Stripe.setPublishableKey("pk_test_Casd");
  }
}
```

Everything seems to work (`VSCODE` diesn't warning me about anything). Nevertheless, when I'm trying to run webpack I'm getting above error.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

So, in short:

1. I'm using `@types/stripe`.
2. I'm importing it into typescript code using `import 'stripe'`.
3. webpack is getting me a `can't resolve stripe module`.

Comment: try removing the import - the import implies that you're loading something from node_modules, which you aren't

Comment: You may have to declare a Typescript module for Stripe so the typescript compiler doesn't complain, but you can address that after

Comment: Nevertheless, Typescript is getting me an `Cannot find name 'Stripe'` on `Stripe.setPublishableKey("..."`

Comment: but does your site bundle properly and work?  you can address the typescript error after

Comment: I've missed to comment that I'm using `@types/stripe`. I'm importing it using `import 'stripe'`.

Comment: well, @types/stripe will be the type definitions for the node module stripe, which is the server side version, which is not what you're using.

Comment: As you can see [on here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe) and as far I've been able to figure out, this library only contains type definitions and it's not intended only on server-side javascript, isn't it? It's for general typescript projects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you get type information for the client side Stripe.js but if you're just trying to get up and running, you can do the following:

```
export class SourceEffects {
  constructor() {
    let Stripe: any = (window as <any>).Stripe;
    Stripe.setPublishableKey("pk_test_Casd");
  }
}
```

Basically, the script tag for Stripe.js adds a Stripe object to the window object, so just take the object from there and just turn off the type checking for that API. If you want typing information for the client-side Stripe.js, you'll have to look around for it (or write it yourself). But the use of `any` will turn off type checking for Stripe.

See [this blog post](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/07/05/using-stripe-payment-with-angular-2/) for a full example.

PS. You still need to remove the `import 'stripe'` line.

**EDIT: Why Your Solution Doesn't Work**

**- I'm using @types/stripe.**
This is solely for the typescript compiler to get the type definitions for the node module 'stripe'. This is not used to run your application, which is why you are supposed to only add it to your devDependencies

**- I'm importing it into typescript code using import 'stripe'.**
`import 'stripe'` is an instruction to webpack to find the module `'stripe'` in your node_modules. You don't have that module - you're not using the node library stripe.

**- webpack is getting me a can't resolve stripe module.**
Since you don't have `'stripe'` listed in your package.json (and installed) as a library you are using, webpack can't find it when it tries to load it.

Comment: As far I've been able to see, Stripe.js is only available using script tag. Have you been able to look at some stripe.js npm package? I'm using it in browser.

Comment: This library is for server-side javascript!